# Iterate thru checkbox in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, checkbox

I am currently having some problem with the logic when iterate thru checkbox and perform query in JavaScript. Here is how I set up my checkbox:

```
content += "<tr><td><input id='nssConfirmed' class=\"nssConfirmed\" type=\"checkbox\" onclick=\"queryNSS()\">Confirmed</td></tr>";
content += "<tr><td><input id='nssReserved' class=\"nssReserved\" type=\"checkbox\" onclick=\"queryNSS()\">Reserved</td></tr>";
```

I gave both of them different ID so I can perform some logic here:

```
var filterString = "";
var type_filter = "";
$(":checkbox").each(function(index, element) {     
    if($(this).is(':checked'))       
    {
        if(document.getElementById("nssConfirmed").checked)
        {               
            type_filter = "C";
            filterString += "site_status in ('" + type_filter + "')";
        }
        else if (document.getElementById("nssReserved").checked)
        {
            type_filter = "R";
            filterString += "site_status in ('" + type_filter + "')";
        }  
        else if (document.getElementById("nssConfirmed").checked && document.getElementById(""nssReserved"))
        {
            type_filter = "1=1";
            filterString += "site_status in ('" + type_filter + "')";
        } 
        else
        {
            type_filter = "1=1";
            filterString += "site_status in ('" + type_filter + "')";
        }           
    }
});
```

My situation is:

- if nssConfirmed is checked only, the filterString should be site_status in ("C")
- if nssReserved is checked only, the filterString should be site_status in ("R")
- if none or both of them were checked, the filterString should be site_status in ("1=1")

However, when I try to debug, it skips the process of iterate of each checkbox and returning me null for filterString. It was working when I try to implement it with just only if and else statement without iterate thru checkboxes.

I wonder why is it so. Thanks in advance.

Comment: check second else if  you got syntax wrong there

Comment: Following the code path of this looks like you're doing a loop and inside your loop a lookup for each node, so you're repeating yourself however many times you have checkboxes on the page. Further, `if (a) {} else if (b) {} else if (a && b) {/* this will never be reached and should be before if (a) and if (b) */} else {}`

Comment: Is there any better way to amend this portion of code? Because I need to loop thru each checkbox everytime to check for the statement. I did it with if else previously and it works this way: if I check nssConfirmed, it return me "C". And I check nssReserved again together with checked nssConfirmed, it only returns me "R" instead of "1=1"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you're not really using your loop and are looking up by *id*, you can shorten your code considerably by dropping the unused loop and cacheing the lookup.
Further, your check for `confirmed && reserved` needs to be **before** the check for `confirmed` and **before** the check for `reserved` in your `if..else` structure, or it'll never be reached. You also have a syntax error in your posted code (notice how the code's colours are in your question).

```
var filterString = "",
    type_filter = "",
    confirmed = document.getElementById("nssConfirmed").checked,
    reserved = document.getElementById("nssReserved").checked;
if (confirmed && reserved) {
    type_filter = "1=1";
} else if (confirmed) {
    type_filter = "C";
} else if (reserved) {
    type_filter = "R";
} else {
    type_filter = "1=1";
}
filterString += "site_status in ('" + type_filter + "')";
```